# Android Best way to access data and if so how to populate the Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, parsing, pdf, text

So, I have data contained in a table of 3 columns with a few hundred rows in PDFs which will get updated quarterly at this time I don't know if they can be presented to me in any other form.  I using the ZXing barcode scanner to check against this data to see if the scanned UPC is within it to let the user know if it is an authorized item.  I assume I have to save the PDF as Text and then somehow import this information into a SQLite DB and that way I can give the user all the information contained in that row and then from there I can use this information to allow the app to do other things.  Unfortunately, when the PDF is saved as text it just separates everything by spaces, so I don't see an easy way to import these into the DB and have them separated into the appropriate columns.  Would I need to manually go in and add delimiters and then parse the data to load it into the DB?  Or am I looking in the completely wrong way or making any sense at all?

I need this be flexible for updating which is why I think using SQLite DB is the best method and hoping that I can create the DB at install of the app, so it is only populated the one time until I release the update with the new data.

Thanks in advance for help, I think I am close just trying to get pointed in the right direction.